# RxJava chain to a database and a server

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I'm trying to create a good chain. I think this question is popular and has been asked, but I haven't found it.

**So what I want is to go to the database and if I don't have anything inside it, I want to download info from the server.**

Here is the code:

```
() -> loadPriceListFromDatabase.call(null)
                        .flatMap(mealTypes -> {
                            if (mealTypes.size() != 0 ) {
                                return Observable.just(mealTypes); //here is the place where I'm not sure about code style.
                            }
                            return loadPriceList.call(null)
                                    .map(model -> {
                                        preferences.setPriceListDate(model.getDate().getTime());
                                        return ActiveAndroidHelper.saveMeals(model);
                                    });
                        })
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()),
                MainActivity::onTestLoaded,
                BaseActivity::onError
```

So how should I do this? Any **must use** examples?

**UPD**

I want to put any condition I want inside if\else block.

```
if (mealTypes.size() != 0 ) {
```

not only something is null or zero. 
For example I can say

```
if (date == currentDate) { (//where date is timestamp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as:

```
Observable.concat(
  databaseObservable.filter(databaseItem -> databaseItem.date ==     currentDate) ,
  networkObservable
).take(1).subscribe(...)
```

It won't subscribe to the networkObservable unless your databaseObservable completes without onNext.

Comment: but where is the if\else? I think my database will continue in either case, the thing is it can return the list with zero elements.

Comment: There is no need for if/else what it does is: subscribe to the databaseObservable until it completes ( because the concat )

Comment: And after the complete of database go for the network, but as we have the take(1), if the database calls onNext it will finish before calling the network. If the databaseObservable returns an Observable.empty() it will subscribe the networkObservable.

Comment: For a more detailed explanation Dan Lew published an article time ago: http://blog.danlew.net/2015/06/22/loading-data-from-multiple-sources-with-rxjava/

Answer (score 0):

Use **swtichIfEmpty** operator, in case your observable is empty automatically you can provide a new one in the pipeline.

Check this example

```
@Test
public void testSwitchPerson() {
    Observable.just(new ArrayList<>())
              .flatMap(persons -> Observable.from(persons)
                                            .switchIfEmpty(Observable.just(new Person("new", 0, "no_sex"))))
              .subscribe(System.out::println);

}
```

if you want to see more practical example check here https://github.com/politrons/reactive